# Flow: Date is incompatible with string

Tags: javascript, flowtype

```js
import is from "is_js";
function handle_date_string(dateObj: Date | string): string {
  const result = is.date(dateObj) ? dateObj.toDateString() : dateObj;
  return result;
}
```

What this function does - if it receives a Date object, it converts it to date string, otherwise passes a recieved string.
Flow reports these errors:

> Error:(21, 45) Cannot call `dateObj.toDateString` because property `toDateString` is missing in  `String` [1].
>   Error:(22, 10) Cannot return `result` because  `Date` [1] is incompatible with  string [2].

Answer (score 0):

Flow cannot infer that `is.date()` guarantees that `dateObj` in the first branch will be a `Date` object. Instead use `dateObj instanceof Date ? ...`.

Comment: hmm... is there any other way to do it using `is.js`? the whole point of using that lib is that to get rid of `typeof` & `instanceof` checks.     
I've even converted `is.js` definition from DefinitelyTyped into flow-typed and still Flow is unhappy

Comment: It doesn't look like custom predicate functions for type refinement are possible according to [this issue thread](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/34). You could write your own `isDate` function that uses `%checks` and `instanceof`, but, as you mentioned, that defeats the purpose of using `is.js`.